# Java NIO TCP server with IDLE TIMEOUT on clients

Tags: java, timeout, nio

I trying to create a TCP server using NIO(Selector based) which can check whether any client is idle for more than 5 minutes.

I had been using time out on read operations using blocking IO, but there is no such option is provided in NIO.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by periodically checking idle clients.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.StandardSocketOptions;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * {@link NIOServer} class is used to create a Non-Blocking TCP server listening
 * on the port specified in the constructor parameter and listens for clients
 * sending data.
 * 
 * @author AchuthaRanga.Chenna
 * 
 */
public class NIOServer implements Runnable {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private InetAddress hostAddress;
    private int port;
    private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
    private Selector selector;
    private boolean runServer = true;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<SocketChannel, Long> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<SocketChannel, Long>();

    /**
     * Constructor to pass the host and port of server.
     * 
     * @param hostAddress
     *            address on which server has to be run.
     * @param port
     *            port of the server.
     **/
    public NIOServer(InetAddress hostAddress, int port) throws IOException {
        this.hostAddress = hostAddress;
        this.port = port;
        this.selector = initSelector();
        IdleSocketChecker isc = new IdleSocketChecker();
        new Thread(isc).start();
    }

    /**
     * Method to create a ServerSocket and register to selector with option
     * OP_ACCEPT to accept connections from clients.
     * 
     * @return Selector registered with a serverSocket listening on a port to
     *         accept connections.
     * @throws IOException
     *             on fail to create a selector or bind the server to the
     *             address.
     */

    private Selector initSelector() throws IOException {
        Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
        this.serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(this.hostAddress, this.port);
        serverSocketChannel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(isa);
        serverSocketChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        return socketSelector;
    }

    /**
     * Method with a infinite loop to iterate over the selected keys of the
     * selector to know the option interested of the client sockets connected.
     * Loop breaks when on IOException occurs on the selector which is listening
     * for IOOperations of the client.
     **/
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (runServer) {
            try {
                /*
                 * ".select" is a blocking call which invokes when any channel
                 * registered with the selector has an I/O operation to be done.
                 */
                this.selector.select();
                /*
                 * Get a Iterator of the channels having I/O event to be
                 * handled.
                 */
                Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                /* Iterate over the selected keys having I/O event to be done. */
                while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                    /* Remove the key to avoid infinite loop. */
                    selectedKeys.remove();
                    try {
                        if (!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                            this.accept(key);
                        } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                            this.read(key);
                        }
                    } catch (CancelledKeyException e) {// key has been canceled
                    }
                }
                /* Exception is generated when the Selector fails. */
                /*
                 * Close the server and return from the while loop when Selector
                 * fails.
                 */
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("[run] Exception on generation of client event", e);
                try {
                    serverSocketChannel.close();
                    selector.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    logger.error("[run] Exception on shutting down NIOSERVER due to selector is closed", e1);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        logger.info("[NIOSERVER thread closed normally]");
        /* Clean up the resources */
        this.releaseResources();
    }

    /**
     * Method to release the resources used to create NIOSERVER SOCKET.
     */
    public void releaseResources() {
        try {
            this.serverSocketChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("[run]", e);
        }
        try {
            this.selector.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("[run]", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to return socket status.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isConencted() {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            status = serverSocketChannel.isOpen();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to stop the server thread.
     * 
     * @param runServer
     *            Flag decides to stop Server
     */
    public void shutDown() {
        this.runServer = false;
        logger.info("[shutDown] Server is stopped");
    }

    /**
     * Method to accept connections from clients and registering for reading
     * data from clients.Set's a KeepAlive option of the socket true and
     * register the connected socket for READ option.
     * 
     * @param key
     *            which is ready to acceptable
     */
    private void accept(SelectionKey key) {
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        try {
            SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
            if (socketChannel != null) {
                /* Set the KeepAlive flag to avoid continuous open of files */
                socketChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
                socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                /* Register the client connected with our interested Option Read */
                socketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                // key.attach(System.currentTimeMillis());
                clients.put(socketChannel, System.currentTimeMillis());
                logger.debug("[accept] New Client connected from " + socketChannel.getRemoteAddress());
                logger.info("[accept] Total connected : " + clients.size());
//              System.out.println(socketChannel.hashCode());
            } else {
                key.cancel();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            key.cancel();
            logger.error("[accept] Error while accepting new connectins", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * * Method to read data from key having read event pending.
     * 
     * @param key
     *            SelectionKey having read event.
     */
    private void read(SelectionKey key) {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        synchronized (socketChannel) {
            if (socketChannel.isOpen()) {
                try {
                    ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(150);
                    readBuffer.clear();
                    int numRead = 0;
                    try {
                        /* ".read" is nonblocking */
                        numRead = socketChannel.read(readBuffer);
                        /*
                         * Some other IO error on reading socketChannel.
                         */
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.debug("[run] Connection abruptly terminated from client", e);
                        key.channel().close();
                        clients.remove(socketChannel);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (numRead == -1) {// socket closed cleanly
                        key.channel().close();
                        clients.remove(socketChannel);
                        return;
                    }
                    String data = null;
                    data = new String(readBuffer.array(), Charset.forName("ASCII"));
                    logger.info(data);
                    /* Send the read data to the DataDispatcher Actor */
                    clients.put(socketChannel, System.currentTimeMillis());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.debug("[run] ", e);
                    return;
                }
            } else {// socketChannel is closed
                try {
                    key.channel().close();// Sanitary close operation
                    clients.remove(key);
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        logger.info("[checkIdleSockets] Total connected : " + clients.size());
    }

    /**
     * Method to check the sockets idle for 15 minutes and close the socket.
     */
    private void checkIdleSockets() {
//      synchronized (clients) {
            Iterator<Entry<SocketChannel, Long>> iter = clients.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    Map.Entry<SocketChannel, Long> entry = iter.next();
                    SocketChannel client = entry.getKey();
                    long mills = entry.getValue();
                    double minutes = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mills) / (double) (1000 * 60);
                    if (minutes > 5) {
                        /* key is idle for */
                        logger.info("[IdleSocketChecker] Socket is idle for " + Math.round(minutes) + ", closing......");
                        try {
                            client.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        } finally {
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.info("[IdleSocketChecker] ", e);
                }
            }
//      }
        logger.info("[checkIdleSockets] Total connected : " + clients.size());
    }

    /**
     * {@link IdleSocketChecker} is a thread to check for any idle sockets in
     * the selector.
     * 
     * @author AchuthaRanga.Chenna
     * 
     */
    private class IdleSocketChecker implements Runnable {
        private boolean RUN = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (RUN) {
                    /* Wait for 5 Minutes */
                    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
                    checkIdleSockets();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.warn("[IdleSocketChecker]<run> IdleSocketChecker thread stopped", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some synchronisation there, both to preserve the map and to ensure you don't close sockets while you're processing them in the select thread.  There's a easy way to get part of it done. It isn't as accurate as what you've implemented in your answer but it does catch some cases. Just use a select timeout, and note when it triggers (`select()` returns zero). When this happens, close every registered channel except the server socket channel(s).